# Sinatra with WebBrick and OpenSSL / HTTPS with Rack::Auth::Basic

Tags: https, openssl, sinatra, yaml, rack

I have read the tutorials and documentation on creating an OpenSSL certificate, and getting the Webbrick server running with it and Sinatra. This is all working - and thanks to prior posts on this. However, now that i try to integrate this with my app, i seem to be losing the 'before do' code that parses the request and allowed me to pull the authenticated username out of the credentials. So, my basic question is - how to use both Rack::Auth::Basic and HTTPS at the same time with WebBrick running in conjunction with Sinatra. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
require 'sinatra'
require 'webrick'
require 'webrick/https'
require 'openssl'

require 'yaml'

# basic authentication provided through Rack:Auth
configure do
  puts "configure do ran"
  # load password file - might move to DB at some point
  @@config = YAML.load_file(File.join(Dir.pwd, 'config', 'users.yml'))  
  use Rack::Auth::Basic, "Restricted Area" do |u, p|
    puts "use Rack::Auth::Basic"
    [u, p] == [u, @@config[:users][u][:password]]
  end
end

before do
  puts "before do ran"
  @auth ||=  Rack::Auth::Basic::Request.new(request.env)
  puts "auth username: " + @auth.username.to_s
  # set the user name for processing  in the post or get
  @myuser = @auth.username.to_s
end

class MyServer  < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    # code would do something with @myuser here
    "Hello, world!"
  end       
end

pkey = cert = cert_name = nil

begin
  pkey = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.open("private_key.pem").read)
  cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.open("certificate.pem").read)
end

webrick_options = {
    :Port               => 8443,
    :Logger             => WEBrick::Log::new($stderr, WEBrick::Log::DEBUG),
    :DocumentRoot       => "/ruby/htdocs",
    :SSLEnable          => true,
    :SSLVerifyClient    => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE,
    :SSLCertificate     => cert,
    :SSLPrivateKey      => pkey,
    :SSLCertName        => [ [ "CN",WEBrick::Utils::getservername ] ],
    :app                  => MyServer
}

Rack::Server.start webrick_options
```

Again, any thoughts on this are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Further playing with this, turns out moving the 'configure do' and the 'before do' into the server class seems to work. Additionally, i have added Rack::SslEnforcer to the code - not sure this is needed though with the web server running only https.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comment above, the following seems to work fine.

```
class MyServer  < Sinatra::Base
  # basic authentication provided through Rack:Auth
  configure do
    puts "Configure do ran"

    # require SSL
    use Rack::SslEnforcer 
    set :session_secret, 'asdfa2342923422f1adc05c837fa234230e3594b93824b00e930ab0fb94b'

    use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => '_rack_session',
                       :path => '/',
                       :expire_after => 2592000, # In seconds
                       :secret => session_secret

    # load password file - might move to DB at some point
    @@config = YAML.load_file(File.join(Dir.pwd, 'config', 'users.yml'))  
    use Rack::Auth::Basic, "Restricted Area" do |u, p|
      puts "use Rack::Auth::Basic"
      [u, p] == [u, @@config[:users][u][:password]]
    end
  end

  before do
    puts "Before do ran"
    @auth ||=  Rack::Auth::Basic::Request.new(request.env)
    puts "auth username: " + @auth.username.to_s
    # set the user name for processing  in the post or get
    @myuser = @auth.username.to_s
  end

  get '/' do
    # code would do something with @myuser here
    "Hello, world!"
  end
end
```